# apoc functions not available with Nepo4j even after the plugin in installed

Tags: neo4j

For some reason, I cannot access apoc functions for Neo4j. I tried with Neo4j installer (4.2.1), and then with Neo4j Desktop (4.2.3, 4.2.1). Restated multiple times. No luck whatsoever.

Example :

```
 RETURN apoc.date.parse("2020-11-04", "ms", "yyyy-MM-dd") AS outputInMs; 

 Error : Unknown function 'apoc.date.parse';
```

Any advice what could I be doing wrong? Have spent 3 hrs trying this but no luck.

Thanks

Manoj Joshi

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the instructions on this website:
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/

1. If your neo4j version is 4.2.x, download the jar file from here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/download/4.2.0.1/apoc-4.2.0.1-core.jar
2. Save it in your neo4j_home/plugins folder
3. Change your neo4j_home/conf/neo4j.conf file by adding this: `dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*`  Then restart your neo4j

Comment: What I found very interesting is where in the neo4j.conf file, you add dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*. At first I added that somewhere in the beginning - after - "dbms.directories.transaction.logs.root". It did not work then. But then I added it after "dbms.security.procedures.allowlist" and it worked. I could be wrong but just sharing what I noticed. Any way, I am so glad it worked. Thanks so much once more.

Comment: glad it worked; pls upvote and accept my answer. thanks